# How to download & store k3s locally so that I can avoid github or internet calls

Tags: kubernetes, k3s

I am currently using command `curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io` to download k3s. The script **[get.k3s.io](https://get.k3s.io/)** is using third party internet calls to URLs:

```
GITHUB_URL=https://github.com/k3s-io/k3s/releases
STORAGE_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/k3s-ci-builds
```

I want to avoid the above calls to URLs and want same k3s package to be stored locally in my personal github project location and download/read it from there. Can some one let me know the steps/procedure to edit this script or download and store k3s locally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

K3s GitHub page has instructions for [Manual Download](https://github.com/k3s-io/k3s#manual-download). You just download the appropriate version from [releases](https://github.com/k3s-io/k3s/releases), and use it like any other binary.

Downloaded binary is not executable by default. You have to make it so, before using it

```text
chmod +x k3s
```

If you want `k3s` to be available system-wide, you need to put it in correct location (e.g. `/usr/local/bin`)

```text
sudo mv k3s /usr/local/bin
```

If you skip the above step, replace `k3s` with `./k3s` in the steps below.

```text
sudo k3s server &
# Kubeconfig is written to /etc/rancher/k3s/k3s.yaml
sudo k3s kubectl get nodes

# On a different node run the below. NODE_TOKEN comes from
# /var/lib/rancher/k3s/server/node-token on your server
sudo k3s agent --server https://myserver:6443 --token ${NODE_TOKEN}
```

<sup>[[source](https://github.com/k3s-io/k3s#manual-download)]</sup>

Alternatively you can [clone the repository](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/creating-and-managing-repositories/cloning-a-repository), and replace the URLs in the script with your repo. I'm not sure, however, how well it would work.

`STORAGE_URL` variable is used to download specific commit version. For it to work `INSTALL_K3S_COMMIT` environment variable must be set prior. You should not be concerned by it, unless you are a developer or a QA.

Comment: @p10I : How is your way of manually download different from https://rancher.com/docs/k3s/latest/en/installation/install-options/#options-for-installation-from-binary ? There are some Air-gapped installation also suggested on rancher page https://rancher.com/docs/k3s/latest/en/installation/airgap/#install-options

Comment: It's not. This is exactly the same procedure.

Comment: @p10l : I followed your ans link. After downloading `k3s` on my linux ubuntu machine from [Assets](https://github.com/k3s-io/k3s/releases/tag/v1.22.3+k3s1) followed by command  `sudo k3s server &`  , It gives me error  `k3s: command not found` . What all things I need to download from [Assets](https://github.com/k3s-io/k3s/releases/tag/v1.22.3+k3s1)? Its not clear.

Comment: I assumed you know how to deal with linux binaries. Updated my answer to add instructions on how to make it executable.

Comment: @p10l : I am stuck [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69899989/kubernetes-service-failing-while-offline-without-internet-k3s-installation) . Can you help ?

Comment: I'll se what I can do, however, since it is a different question, it should be processed in different topic. If you found my answer for this question helpful, consider [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), so the question won't stay unanswered, and people facing similar issue in the future will have easier time finding a solution.