# kubernetes Service failing while offline (without internet) k3s installation

Tags: kubernetes, k3s

I am trying to do [offline setup of k3s](https://rancher.com/docs/k3s/latest/en/installation/airgap/#install-options) i.e. without internet connectivity for *Single Server Configuration* by below steps, but at the end k3s service status is `loaded` instead of `active` and the `default/kube-system` pods not coming up.

I Downloaded k3s binary from [Assets](https://github.com/k3s-io/k3s/releases/tag/v1.22.3+k3s1) and [install.sh script](https://get.k3s.io/), then:

1. `cp /home/my-ubuntu/k3s /usr/local/bin/`
2. `cd /usr/local/bin/`
3. `chmod 770 k3s` - giving executable rights to k3s binary
4. placed [airgap-images-amd64.tar](https://github.com/k3s-io/k3s/releases/download/v1.22.3%2Bk3s1/k3s-airgap-images-amd64.tar) image at `/var/lib/rancher/k3s/agent/images/`
5. `mkdir /etc/rancher/k3s`
6. `cp /home/my-ubuntu/k3s.yaml /etc/rancher/k3s` - copying k3s config file from different machine (because when I tried without config file, I cant set export variable (Step 7) & can't get to see default pods by `kubectl get all -A`). I think I am mistaken at this step, please confirm.
7. `chmod 770 /etc/rancher/k3s/k3s.yaml`
8. `export KUBECONFIG=/etc/rancher/k3s/k3s.yaml` - setting KUBECONFIG env. variable
9. `INSTALL_K3S_SKIP_DOWNLOAD=true ./install.sh`

Error in `journalctl -xe`:

```text
    -- Unit k3s.service has begun starting up.
    Nov 09 19:11:51 my-ubuntu sh[14683]: + /usr/bin/systemctl is-enabled --quiet nm-cloud-setup.service
    Nov 09 19:11:51 my-ubuntu sh[14683]: /bin/sh: 1: /usr/bin/systemctl: not found
    Nov 09 19:11:51 my-ubuntu k3s[14695]: time="2021-11-09T19:11:51.488895919+05:30" level=fatal msg="no default routes found in \"/proc/net/route\" or \"/proc/net/ipv6_route\""
    Nov 09 19:11:51 my-ubuntu systemd[1]: k3s.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
    Nov 09 19:11:51 my-ubuntu systemd[1]: k3s.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
    Nov 09 19:11:51 my-ubuntu systemd[1]: Failed to start Lightweight Kubernetes.
    -- Subject: Unit k3s.service has failed
    -- Defined-By: systemd
    -- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
    -- Unit k3s.service has failed.
-- The result is RESULT.
Nov 09 19:11:56 shreya-Virtual-Machine systemd[1]: k3s.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Nov 09 19:11:56 shreya-Virtual-Machine systemd[1]: k3s.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 20.
-- Subject: Automatic restarting of a unit has been scheduled
```

**PS:** At this stage, the moment I connect this machine to internet, below default pods started coming for command `kubectl get all -A`:

```text
NAMESPACE     NAME                                      READY
kube-system   metrics-server-86cbb8457f-rthkn           1/1
kube-system   helm-install-traefik-crd-w6wgf            1/1
kube-system   helm-install-traefik-m7lkg                1/1
kube-system   svclb-traefik-x6qbc                       2/2
kube-system   traefik-97b44b794-98nkl                   1/1
kube-system   local-path-provisioner-5ff76fc89d-l8825   1/1
kube-system   coredns-7448499f4d-br6tm                  1/1
```

**My aim is simply install k3s without internet connectivity (offline) & get all these pods up running.** Please let me what am I missing here?

Comment: Did you add https://github.com/k3s-io/k3s/releases/download/v1.22.3%2Bk3s1/k3s-airgap-images-amd64.tar in /var/lib/rancher/k3s/agent/images/ (see https://rancher.com/docs/k3s/latest/en/installation/airgap/) ?

Comment: @mpromonet: Yes I have updated my que

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/k3s-io/k3s/issues/1103) for offline installation- default gateway need to be set.

follow [this comment](https://github.com/k3s-io/k3s/issues/1144#issuecomment-559316077), it should work.

> [aiops@7 ~]$ ip route
> 172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1
> 192.168.100.0/24 dev ens192 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.100.7 metric 100
> sudo ip route add default via 192.168.100.1